# Why does this query doesn't use index for ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, sql-order-by, query-optimization

```
SELECT `f`.*
FROM `files_table` `f`
WHERE f.`application_id` IN(6)
AND `f`.`project_id` IN(130418)
AND `f`.`is_last_version` = 1
AND `f`.`temporary` = 0
AND f.deleted_by is null
ORDER BY `f`.`date` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

When I remove the ORDER BY, query executes in 0.1 seconds. With the ORDER BY it takes 3 seconds.

There is an index on every WHERE column and there is also an index on ORDER BY field (date).

What can I do to make this query faster? Why is ORDER BY slowing it down so much? Table has 3M rows.

Comment: Index on every column will not help to optimze order by you need to create a multicolumn index to optimize order by its in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: So you're saying a combined index on all those fields should work, instead of individual index on all columns?

Comment: update your questiona and add your table schema  ..

Comment: Maybe Descending Indexes is what you need? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

instead of an index on each column in where be sure you have a composite index  that cover all the columns in where

eg

```
create index  idx1 on files_table (application_id, project_id,is_last_version,temporary,deleted_by)
```

avoid  IN clause for single value use  = for these

```
  SELECT `f`.*
  FROM `files_table` `f`
  WHERE f.`application_id`  = 6 
  AND `f`.`project_id` = 130418
  AND `f`.`is_last_version` = 1
  AND `f`.`temporary` = 0
  AND f.deleted_by is null
  ORDER BY `f`.`date` DESC
  LIMIT 5
```

the date  or others column in select could be useful  retrive all info using the index  and avoiding  the access to the table data .. but for select  all (select *) 
 you probably need  severl columns an then the access  to the table data  is done however ..   but you can try an eval the performance  ..

be careful to place the data non involved  in where at the right of all the column involved  in where

```
create index  idx1 on files_table (application_id, project_id,is_last_version,temporary,deleted_by, date)
```

Comment: Does the date field also need to be in composite index?

Comment: That is, "If the index can get entirely through the `WHERE` clause _and_ the `ORDER BY`, then the query can stop after `LIMIT` rows."

Comment: No never   ...  the query  select all the rows ..  produce the temporary result  ..  perform the order by and when the ordered  result is done .. select only the limit. ... the order by don't use index ..   you can only produce faster query  ...  using proper index